# osgi-jax-rs-connector ClassNotFoundException javax.servlet.Filter

Tags: java, jersey, osgi, jax-rs, equinox

I proceed to this tutorial 
http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/02/04/step-by-step-how-to-bring-jax-rs-and-osgi-together/
and standalone it works fine for me. 
Now i want to integrate it with my other bundles and got into the following exception:

```
!ENTRY com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher 4 0 2014-09-16 14:11:27.203
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.Activator.start() of bundle com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.JerseyContext.<init>(JerseyContext.java:43)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.JAXRSConnector.createJerseyContext(JAXRSConnector.java:185)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.JAXRSConnector.doAddHttpService(JAXRSConnector.java:74)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.JAXRSConnector.addHttpService(JAXRSConnector.java:67)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.HttpTracker.addingService(HttpTracker.java:32)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.HttpTracker.addingService(HttpTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:941)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:318)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:261)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.Activator.openHttpServiceTracker(Activator.java:70)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.Activator.start(Activator.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter cannot be found by com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.jersey-all_2.10.1
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 45 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.JerseyContext.<init>(JerseyContext.java:43)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.JAXRSConnector.createJerseyContext(JAXRSConnector.java:185)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.JAXRSConnector.doAddHttpService(JAXRSConnector.java:74)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.JAXRSConnector.addHttpService(JAXRSConnector.java:67)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.HttpTracker.addingService(HttpTracker.java:32)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.HttpTracker.addingService(HttpTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:941)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:318)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:261)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.Activator.openHttpServiceTracker(Activator.java:70)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.Activator.start(Activator.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter cannot be found by com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.jersey-all_2.10.1
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 45 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-09-16 14:11:27.206
!MESSAGE Bundle com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher_4.1.0.201407081443 [101] is not active.
```

as i mentioned before its the example but with my other bundles.
All bundles are listed below:

```
0   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.0.v20140606-1445
39  ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215
40  ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036
41  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.persistence.core_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
42  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.persistence.asm_3.3.1.v201302191223
43  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.persistence.jpa_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
44  ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201212101605
47  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.persistence.antlr_3.2.0.v201302191141
48  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.4.0.v20140312-2051
49  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi.util_3.3.0.v20131023-1243
50  ACTIVE      osgi.enterprise_4.2.0.201003190513
51  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
52  ACTIVE      javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213
53  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.0.v20140131-1639
56  ACTIVE      org.apache.derby_10.8.2.2
62  ACTIVE      de.sambalmueslie.zitadelle.container_1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
66  ACTIVE      de.sambalmueslie.zitadelle.entity_1.0.0.qualifier
69  ACTIVE      de.sambalmueslie.zitadelle.common_1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
73  ACTIVE      de.sambalmueslie.zitadelle.data_1.0.0.qualifier
74  ACTIVE      de.sambalmueslie.zitadelle.module.town_mgt_1.0.0.qualifier
75  ACTIVE      de.sambalmueslie.zitadelle.module.session_mgt_1.0.0.qualifier
78  ACTIVE      com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.jersey-all_2.10.1
80  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.persistence.core_2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b
81  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.continuation_8.1.14.v20131031
82  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.1.500.v20140318-1755
83  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.14.v20131031
84  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.http_8.1.14.v20131031
85  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.14.v20131031
86  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.200.v20131021-1843
87  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.14.v20131031
89  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.io_8.1.14.v20131031
91  ACTIVE      javax.servlet-api_3.0.1
92  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.util_8.1.14.v20131031
93  ACTIVE      de.sambalmueslie.zitadelle.utils_1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
97  ACTIVE      com.google.gson_2.2.4
98  ACTIVE      com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.provider.gson_2.0.0.201407081443
99  ACTIVE      com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.provider.sse_2.0.0.201407081443
101 RESOLVED    com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher_4.1.0.201407081443
102 ACTIVE      de.sambalmueslie.zitadelle.rest_1.0.0.qualifier
```

No changes in Manifest.MF except adding the bundle dependencies:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: ZitadelleRestInterface
Bundle-SymbolicName: de.sambalmueslie.zitadelle.rest
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: de.sambalmueslie.zitadelle.ExampleActivator
Bundle-Vendor: Sambasoft
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Import-Package: javax.servlet;version="3.0.0",
 javax.ws.rs;version="2.0.0",
 javax.ws.rs.core;version="2.0.0",
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.osgi,
 de.sambalmueslie.zitadelle.data;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 de.sambalmueslie.zitadelle.utils;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 de.sambalmueslie.zitadelle.common;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 de.sambalmueslie.zitadelle.module.session_mgt;bundle-version="1.0.0"
```

Could anyone help me please??

Answer (score 0):

after cleaning the osgi cache, it works :-)

**programm arguments**

```
-os ${target.os} 
-ws ${target.ws} 
-arch ${target.arch} 
-nl ${target.nl} 
-consoleLog -console 
-clean
```

**vm arguments**

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 
-Xms40m -Xmx512m 
-Declipse.ignoreApp=true 
-Dosgi.noShutdown=true
-Dorg.osgi.service.http.port=9090
```